# Search API cannot search taxonomy terms

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I have built a search page using Search API, specifically the database version. This search page is a simple view and works exactly how I'd expect it to.

However, now I need to update the index so that it will search taxonomy terms associated with each piece of content. For reference, the field in question is field_author as a piece of content can be associated with several different authors.

From reading online, it seems like I should be able to edit the search index, scroll down to Add Related Fields, add Author, and that makes additional fields show up in the selectable fields to index section.

From there, I check the box beside Author >> Name (field_author:name), click Save Changes, and reindex my field.

However, a search for an author name does not produce any search results and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above steps were correct. Additionally however, you need to add Author >> Name to the Fulltext search filter criteria in the view.